# Mongoose: Populate Array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have these rather complex Schemas in Mongoose:

```
var IPSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    aktuell: {},
    historie: [
        {
        _id:        false,
        date:       { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        changed:    {},
        deleted:    { type: Boolean, default: false },
        userid:     { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
       }
   ]
});

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        local : {
            email        : String,
            password     : String
       }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('IP', IPSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

As you can see the path `IP.historie.userid` is referenced to the User Model. Now I want to run a Query that fetches a IP Document from my collection and populates all the `userid` fields with `email` from the `local` path of the User Schema.

This is my Query Code so far but it is not working:

```
return IP.findById(req.params.id, function(err, ip) {

  User.populate(ip, {path: 'historie.userid', model: 'User'}, function(err, ip){
    console.log(ip.historie.userid.local.email);
  });
```

This is the error Express is showing me:

```
/var/www/kreditoren/routes/routes.js:106
        console.log(ip.historie.userid.local.email);
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'historie' of undefined
```

Note that `historie` is an array and contains many entries, such as:

```
historie: 
   [ { changed: [Object],
       userid: 5431ca5eb8a0c9ed34775f51,
       deleted: false,
       date: Thu Oct 09 2014 22:06:59 GMT+0200 (CEST) },
     { changed: [Object],
       userid: 5431ca5eb8a0c9ed34775f51,
       deleted: false,
       date: Thu Oct 09 2014 21:59:27 GMT+0200 (CEST) },
     { changed: [Object],
       userid: 54340279407667e53192c92a,
       deleted: false,
       date: Thu Oct 02 2014 13:59:30 GMT+0200 (CEST) } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using populate from Mongoose >= 3.6 did the trick:

```
IP.findById(req.params.id).populate('historie.userid').exec(function(err, ip) {

      for (var i=ip.historie.length-1, l=0; l<=i; i--) {

        if (ip.historie[i].userid !== null) {
          console.log(rec_hist[i].userid.local.email);
        } else {
          console.log('user unknown');
        }
      }
```

Outputs the Email field from the Data in the User Model and even checks if a User even exists.